# Instructions for the LEGO Star Wars Holiday X-Wing (4002019)?

Tags: sets, instructions

The 2019 LEGO Employee Gift 4002019 is a holiday-style Star Wars X-Wing Fighter which is a pretty similar build to [the current LEGO Star Wars X-Wing Fighter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0QsW.jpg).

[image]

[image]

Are the instructions for this set available in a digital format anywhere (note that in past years, LEGO has not made these instructions available like they do for publicly released sets)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF's for scanned official building instructions can be found at the very end of set review at [New Elementary](https://www.newelementary.com/2020/01/lego-x-wing-instructions-download-christmas-4002019.html?m=1).

Answer (score 5):

I found [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvOYTE9iX5s) which has pictures for each page in the instruction booklets. The quality is pretty good and each step is readable.

[image]